# C# ComboBox change active status

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I have five `ComboBox` controls and when an item is selected in `ComboBox` `1`, a new list is created in `ComboBox` `2`, and so on down to `ComboBox` `5`. I need to change the active status according to the most current selected item. The items are not selected by way of a `SelectedIndexChanged` event but in the button click event handler. I have been working on some code but have reached an impasse. Here is the code:

```
///////////combo1//////////////////////
int selectedIndex1 = comboBox1.SelectedIndex;
Object selectedItem1 = comboBox1.SelectedItem;                                
if (selectedItem1.ToString() == "Computers")
{    
    selectedItem1 = "32";
    request.categoryId = selectedItem1.ToString();    
}

///////////combo2//////////////////////
int selectedIndex2 = comboBox2.SelectedIndex;
Object selectedItem2 = comboBox2.SelectedItem;            
if (selectedItem2.ToString() == "Laptop")
{
    selectedItem2= "1772";
    request.categoryId = selectedItem2.ToString();
}
```

The problem is that when I do this it does not use the `ComboBox` `2` selected item and does not cancel the `ComboBox` `1` selected item. I need for it to supersede the previous `ComboBox` selected item.

Comment: Your code and your requirements are a bit confusing. Note that to know the last selected item of a combobox in the same moment when the selection occurs, you should rely on an event (for example: SelectedIndexChanged); not sure if you are doing that, but your posted code is certainly not showing it. By relying on the 5 associated events you would be able to update the selectedItem (global) variable with the last selected item. Is this what you want?

Comment: Your question cannot be understood. Please edit and provide proper informations to help others understand what problem you're facing.

Comment: Btw, by assigning selectedItem a new Object() it will never equal any other selected (or not) item (or anything else). Because it's a NEW object.

Comment: i updated my post. I need for the selected item in the list created in combobox 2 as a result of the selected item in combobox 1 to supersede my combobox 1 selection.

Comment: Where you wrote this code? I mean in which event? It is clear that you are not setting any value to your combo boxes in your code, so why you are expecting?

Comment: It is in a button click event and it works but not the second or subsequent combobox selection.

Answer (score 1):

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 Object selectedItem1 = comboBox1.SelectedItem;
 comboBox2.Enabled = true;
 comboBox3.Enabled = false;
 comboBox4.Enabled = false;
 comboBox5.Enabled = false;

 if(selectedItem1.ToString() == "Computers")
 {
   //update data source for comboBox2 with the relevant data for "Computers"
 }

 //remove data for comboBox3 4 and 5 witch are now disabled
}
```

Repeat the idea for the rest.

Comment: Is there a if statement for the "comboBox_SelectedIndexChanged event" that I could use because I want to place the above code in the button click statement.

Comment: I need a bit more context. What does this button do?

Comment: That is not exactly what I wanted it to do. Your code Mihai is disabling all the other non-selected combo boxes.  I have Level 1 categories in combo box 1 and upon selected item I will populate combo box 2 with level 2 categories. My problem is that I need to make 1 category request with selected item in what ever category level I choose. I can make level 1 category request but I am stuck from there.

Comment: That button makes a Web Request. And I have the code for the request in the button click event. When I try to use the combobox_selectIndexChanged event it makes my WebRequest unreachable.

Comment: Aha! I see now you use a button to get the data for the next level. You can just put this code in the button click event.